# How to catch iCloud exceptions in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, icloud

one of my iOS apps uses Core Data with iCloud for a while. While this works fine most of the time there are also problems and crashes every know and then. The problem: I am not able to solve these crashes by catching the exception because I have no idea WHERE to do this.

The latest example for an exception that crashes the app is:

```
2014-02-07 10:23:45.118 MyApp[1410:3707] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](754): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~5508B01E-F77F-4AF1-88DE-2E2F8DC55932:MyAppCloudDB
Using local storage: 1

2014-02-07 10:23:45.892 MyApp[1410:3707] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](754): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~5508B01E-F77F-4AF1-88DE-2E2F8DC55932:MyAppCloudDB
Using local storage: 0

2014-02-07 10:24:28.632 MyApp[1410:1803] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation main](731): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error importing transaction log: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x16177920>
transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x160c3e80>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/M889WYL2LY~com~example~MyApp/MyAppTransactionLogs/User~37B9682D-CED2-5F79-AF06-1FE99E7DEE9E/MyAppCloudDB/SZPp~RKudtVxEBMJzTVTupTv0WjG6i~o9Vj54dlknjc=/8AB09D17-5856-49B9-BE4C-A56451FB1EF4.1.cdt
transactionNumber: 34
, exception: *** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil
User Info: (null)

2014-02-07 10:24:28.661 MyApp[1410:1803] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter operation:failedWithError:](1003): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Import operation encountered an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x162a8b20 {exception=*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil}
userInfo: {
exception = "*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil";
}. While trying to import the log file at the URL: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x16177920>
transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x160c3e80>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/M889WYL2LY~com~example~MyApp/MyAppTransactionLogs/User~37B9682D-CED2-5F79-AF06-1FE99E7DEE9E/MyAppCloudDB/SZPp~RKudtVxEBMJzTVTupTv0WjG6i~o9Vj54dlknjc=/8AB09D17-5856-49B9-BE4C-A56451FB1EF4.1.cdt
transactionNumber: 34

2014-02-07 10:24:28.686 MyApp[1410:1803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:

(0x30b47e83 0x3aea46c7 0x30a82ecb 0x309dd0cb 0x3099f061 0x309a1841 0x31476aa5 0x3151a96d 0x3b38de7b 0x3b38af93 0x3b38e745 0x3b38e9c5 0x3b4b8dff 0x3b4b8cc4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It seems that there is something wrong with the transaction logs. Of course I would like to resolve the problem and keep the app running instead of just crashing it. Therefore I would have to be able to catch and handle the exception. But how can I do this?

I don't even know where this exceptions comes from. I assume that it is thrown by the UIManagedDocument or the UIManagedObjectContext class but I don't know for sure.

Even if I would know that the exception comes from one of these classes I still does not know how to catch it. Some iCloud related class throws the exception in a background thread while importing the transaction logs. All I have in my code is the reference to the instance of UIManagedDocument. Of course I can wrap every call to this instance in a Try-Catch block but the the exception is not thrown when I use/call this instance but when the object does some work on its own.

Is it even possible to catch exceptions like these?

Even if it is not possible to catch and resolve the exception it would great to know that the exception was thrown. This would at least give me the opportunity to handle the issue when the app is launched the next time (show a message to the user, disconnect from iCloud, etc.).

So, what is the best way to handle these exceptions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is unlikely you will find a way to catch the exceptions. They are no doubt on background threads, with none of your methods in the call stack. You could possibly swizzle one of the Apple methods, but it gets very ugly, and is not allowed in the App Store anyway.

Unfortunately the opacity of Core Data + iCloud is a score against it. You don't know how it is supposed to work, and when it does fail like this, you really have no recourse.

I suggest submitting radars, but the best you can probably hope for is that it is fixed in iOS 8.

Worth considering alternative sync frameworks like [TICDS](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync) and [Ensembles](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles), which both work with iCloud. The advantage there is that you at least have the source code, can see what is going wrong, and get fixes often within hours.

(Disclosure: I founded the Ensembles project)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIManagedDocument you need to subclass it and override a few methods to get the errors.  In particular these two

```
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError
{
    LOG(@"Auto-Saving Document");
    return [super contentsForType:typeName error:outError];
}

- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error userInteractionPermitted:(BOOL)userInteractionPermitted
{
    FLOG(@" error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    NSArray* errors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(errors != nil && errors.count > 0) {
        for (NSError *error in errors) {
            FLOG(@" Error: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    } else {
        FLOG(@" error.userInfo = %@", error.userInfo);
    }
}
```

Not sure these will pick up your specific errors.

More on Core Data and iCloud integration here.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/